# SQL Server 2016 using 32-bits ODBC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, odbc, 32bit-64bit, sql-server-2016

I have an installation of SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition and Visual Studio Professional 2015.

There are 2 working ODBC-connections on the machine (server) for 32-bits and 64-bits. Visual Studio uses the 32-bits, which works fine for me.

Now I just found out that SQL Server 2016 only handles 64-bits ODBC's. So the checkbox with 'run as 32-bits' wont work anymore.

Does anyone has a solution for this? I cannot use the 64-bits ODBC in Visual Studio. The problem is I need to run the packages in SSMS.

Thanks in advance and I'm around for some clarification when needed.

Gr. Erik

[Error on 32-bit support for SQL Server 2016](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1BCA.png)

[Message from Integration Services Catalogs about ODBC failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzORZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Installation of the ODBC's were on the wrong server :|

With installing the full features of SSDT you get the 32-bit support in SQL Server 2016.